# Can two PSN profiles use one PSN Plus subscription on different consoles?

Tags: psn

My dad and I both have a ps4. My subscription for PSN Plus went out and my dad has it for a year. I'd like to know if we could share the PSN Plus subscription on different consoles

Comment: Please don't tag your question with random irrelevant tags. The tag system exists for a reason.

Answer (score 1):

You pay one PS Plus subscription per account. You can access the same account on two different devices